# Silence system sound on startup (mac)

Tags: sound, mac, system

I want to silence the mac startup sound on Ubuntu. I completely removed Mac OSX.

My computer is a MacBook Pro 8.1 and I have installed [refind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/) as EFI boot manager.

Comment: Is the sound played before Ubuntu boots?

Comment: Yes it is the tipical mac boot sound. There is a way to switch it off in Mac OSX (http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-silence-the-startup-chime-on-a-mac--cms-21212), but I didn't find one for Linux.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 (but I think it doesn't matter)

Comment: Do you have rEFind installed?

Comment: @linuscl can you go into osx system recovery on boot (Cmd+Alt(Option)+R) ? - you probably can run the nvram command from a terminal without doing a full recovery.

Comment: @RPi Awesomeness yes, I've installed it.

Comment: @fossfreedom it reboots when I type (Cmd+Alt(Option)+R) on boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Reboot with an OSX installation disc or Recovery HD
2. Start the Terminal
3. Issue the command "# /usr/sbin/nvram SystemAudioVolume=%01"

Comment: Only solution for me (it is a bit unconvenient but working)!! :)

Comment: @linuscl Don't forget to award the bounty! It'll run out if you don't.

Comment: Oh, yes of course :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way.

Assuming you're on a Mac, boot into single-user mode by holding down `Command-S` during bootup.  You will be logged into a Mac Terminal.  Run this command:

```
nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00
```

That should disable it completely.

Comment: To use `Command-S` you need to have OSX installed.

Comment: Is that not in firmware?

Comment: Seems to be not in firmware... :(

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu startup sound is located here `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready.ogg`. You can disable it by running the command:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/system-ready{,-disabled}.ogg
```

Comment: I don't want to silence the Ubuntu Login sound.